# Css is added although html element does not have a certain class

Tags: html, css, less

I have a CSS (the style is written in LESS) problem regarding this style:

```
#someId .someClass ul li.active a {
    color: #6B007D !important;
}
```

Everytime a link is entered, the page is reloaded and the li that is it's parent gets class="active" (it is the only class it has). By design the li element does not have a class.

```html
<div id="someId">
...
<div class="someClass">
....
    <li>
        <a href="somelink.htm">Something</a>
    </li>
....
</div>
....
</div>
```

When I checked a li without the "active" class in Developer Tools (in both Chrome and Firefox) it points that the style with the "active" class takes effect anyway. Why is this happening? How can it be prevented?

PS. The !important is legacy code, not my design choice.

**Problem solved, question unaswered**
I rewritten the script that added the css class, so that there are no empty li elements. If it's not active it gets the "notactive" class. It actually works for this problem, but I don't want to add this as an answer, because I want to understand what actually occured?

Comment: I'm lost.  The active class "gets added"?  Can you attempt to explain the specific problem more clearly?

Comment: Impossible to say without further info. There is probably some other styling that takes effect

Comment: Perhaps you're seeing the default browser styling applied to the `:active` state of the link? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Comment: @sbeliv01, I'm pretty sure that's my own style. There are no :active elements on this page, and the Developer Tools are pointing to a LESS of mine.

Comment: @Syjin, is there a way to tell from Developer Tools (for example) what styling could it be?

Answer (score 1):

The style is not from your css, Its a browser default style applied to any anchor element. You can see the same without those css here.

The color #6B007D is different then what is applied currently for anchor text. You can see the text with color #6B007D below the anchor text in the example.

```html
<li>
    <a href="somelink.htm">Something</a>
</li>

<p style="color: #6B007D">Text in color: #6B007D</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes the `<a>` purple (via CSS):

```
<div id="someId">
    <div class="someClass">
        <ul>
            <li class="active">
              <a href="somelink.htm">Something</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't (whether it has the `.active` class or not:

```
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="somelink.htm">Something</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The difference is that the first is wrapped by the specific selectors mentioned in the CSS: `#someId` `.someClass`

To sbeliv01's point, if it's purple without having those selectors around it, or without being .active, then you're just seeing the default browser styling for `:visited` or something.

Comment: Hi, Dave. I corrected the post. The selectors I mentioned are in use. I omitted them because I thought that would give the code more clarity. I corrected that. Please take note, that these are not the only elements there. But the div#someId contains a lot of stuff, while containing a div.someClass where the ul is. Thanks for your answer :-)